# How to reset/reuse deleted row id instead of MAX(id) in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite namely table_a. It's one of the column 'id' is set to auto increment.
I have 5 rows so the ids are 0,1,2,3,4. then I deleted the rows with id 2 & 3. now when I add 3 rows its Id is auto generated as 5,6,7.
But i want it should use the deleted row id i.e 2 and then use 3 then use 5. Any Idea how can this be done.

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you

```
SELECT id + 1 FROM TableName t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1) limit 0,1
```

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2 WHERE t2.id = ? + 1` returns 1 if there is a row with id `?+1`, and `NULL` if it doesn't. If it doesn't, then `?+1` would be a unique index to insert stuff to. So we'll call that inner select `next_id`. The outer statement then is `SELECT id + 1 FROM TableName t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS next_id LIMIT 0,1)` - we search for every index that is a valid index but has a gap above itself and return the next highest integer. Due to `LIMIT 0,1` we only get the smallest one - entries are sorted ascending by `id`, after all.